# How to inject parsed variables into Script string?

Tags: vb.net, csv, cefsharp

Because of VB WebBrowser limitation I use now CefSharp, but got a problem. I'm not familiar with JavaScript language, but have to write code with it. 
Target is fill form and click "add" button, but to fill form I use variables from parsed CSV. How I can inject these variables into script string. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim csv As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim laskut As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(csv).ToArray

    For Each line In laskut
        Dim Fields = line.Split(";"c)
        Dim hinta As String = Fields(10)
        Dim maksaja As String = Fields(5)
        Dim laitos As String = Fields(6)
        Dim asiakas As String = Fields(4)
        Dim osoite As String = Fields(7)
        Dim index As String = Fields(8)
        Dim city As String = Fields(9)
        Dim postal As String = index & " " & city
        Dim day As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Fields(1).Replace("""", ""), "dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim pvm = day.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")

        Dim js As String = <js><![CDATA[document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_name1").value = asiakas;
            document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_street_address1").value = osoite; 
            document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_postal_address").value = postal; 
            document.getElementsById("addProductRow")[0].click();]]></js>.Value

        browser.GetMainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(js)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert variable values into XML literals with `<%= someVariable %>` - as long as it isn't in a CDATA section, from my brief testing. CDATA hasn't been need to hide JavaScript for a long time.

```
        Dim asiakas = "hello"
        Dim osoite = "there"
        Dim postal = "world"

        Dim js = <js>
document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_name1").value = '<%= asiakas %>';
document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_street_address1").value = '<%= osoite %>'; 
document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_postal_address").value = '<%= postal %>'; 
document.getElementsById("addProductRow")[0].click();
</js>.Value

        Console.WriteLine(js)
```

outputs:

> document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_name1").value = 'hello';
>   document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_street_address1").value = 'there';
>   document.getElementById("w_invoice_t_new_inv_postal_address").value = 'world';
>   document.getElementsById("addProductRow")[0].click();

You probably want to put quotes in there (as shown, or double-quotes if preferred) to make them literal strings in the JavaScript.

---

Documentation: [XML Literals Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/xml/xml-literals-overview#embedding-queries-in-xml-literals)